# Unable to click popup elements even after scrolling down python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select add on items to a meal on this website https://www.just-eat.co.uk/restaurants-mcdonalds-victorialondon/menu. However, I've tried everything - Actionchains, waiting for elements to be clickable and ScrollIntoView but nothing has worked. I've also tried maximising the window. Sometimes I get an error that the element isn't clickable as it's blocked by the top or bottom parts of the popup, other times I just get the error unable to locate the element.

Here's a screenshot of one of the popups [image]

Some of the elements are required to be clicked on before the "add to order" button is clickable, I'm searching for the element by matching text
`browser.find_element_by_xpath(f'//span[text()="{element_text}"]')`

For example, I select the 'Pancakes & Sausage Meal' (meals available vary by time of day) by the following: `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[text()="Pancakes & Sausage Meal"]').click()` and then try to click "Regular Latte" by doing `browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Regular Latte"]').click()` but that doesn't work - I've tried using ActionChains and scrolling to the element before clicking it.

```
enter code here
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to close cookies pop-up first there.
In order to accept the cookies you should click element located by `button[data-test-id="accept-all-cookies-button"]` css selector.
With expected conditions explicit wait it will be:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="accept-all-cookies-button"]'))).click()
```

**UPD**
In the add to order pop-up you have to select several required options to enable the "add to order" button. Once that button is enabled you can click it with

```
button[data-test-id="add-to-basket"]
```

css selector.
With expected conditions it will be

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[data-test-id="add-to-basket"]'))).click()
```

Comment: That's not the problem, I clear the cookies button easily earlier on as I'm navigating through the website. Did you manage to select an add on item in the popup?

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question... See the updated answer

Comment: Maybe I've not been clear enough, the problem I'm having is clicking the required options. For example, I select the 'Pancakes & Sausage Meal' by the following: browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h3[text()="Pancakes & Sausage Meal"]').click() and then try to click "Regular Latte" by doing browser.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Regular Latte"]').click() but that doesn't work - I've tried using ActionChains and scrolling to the element before clicking it. (The meal and add on you select is dependent on user input but I've hardcoded it here for the example)